# Merge two model lists

Tags: c#, linq

I want merge two lists. List The lists contain different elements to each other and I want to merge the first list to the second list:

```
var query = (

                from articleA in db.V_Article
                join articleC in db.V_CLIENT_PRIX on articleA.ARTICLE equals articleC.Article
                where articleC.CLIENT == Current_Client_Id
                select new
                {
                    ID = articleA.ID,
                    ARTICLE = articleA.ARTICLE,
                    PRIXVHT = articleC.PrixVHT,
                    REMISE = articleC.Remise,
                    STOCK = articleA.STOCK,
                    FOURNISSEUR = articleA.FRN,
                    FAMILLE = articleA.FAMILLE,
                    UNITE = articleA.Unite,
                    IMAGE = articleA.Image,
                    QUANTITE = 0,
                    CIN = Current_Client_Id,
                    REFERENCE = articleA.REFERENCE,
                    TVA = articleA.TVA,
                    PRIXVTTC = tarifclient == 0 ? articleA.PrixVTTC : tarifclient == 1 ? articleA.T1_PrixTTC : tarifclient == 2 ? articleA.T2_PrixTTC : articleA.T3_PrixTTC,
                });


        list1 = query.ToList() ;
```

and this is the second list:

```
var article = (

                from articleA in db.V_Article
                where !tabEnc.Contains(articleA.ID)
                select new
                {
                    ID = articleA.ID,
                    ARTICLE = articleA.ARTICLE,
                    PRIXVHT = articleA.PrixVHT,
                    REMISE = 0,
                    STOCK = articleA.STOCK,
                    FOURNISSEUR = articleA.FRN,
                    FAMILLE = articleA.FAMILLE,
                    UNITE = articleA.Unite,
                    IMAGE = articleA.Image,
                    QUANTITE = 0,
                    CIN = Current_Client_Id,
                    REFERENCE = articleA.REFERENCE,
                    TVA = articleA.TVA,
                    PRIXVTTC = tarifclient == 0 ? articleA.PrixVTTC : tarifclient == 1 ? articleA.T1_PrixTTC : tarifclient == 2 ? articleA.T2_PrixTTC : articleA.T3_PrixTTC,
                }).ToList;
```

I want to merge (concatenate) these two lists - how can I do it?

Comment: Can you explain (in English preferably) what you mean by "merge"?  Do you want the result to have the same number of rows but concatenate some values or do you want the two sets concatenated (e.g. if each had 10 rows the result will have 20 rows)?

Comment: You can use "Union": var finalList = list1.Union(article)

Comment: Or var final = list1.Concat(list2); if you know there isn't going to be any dupe data.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx) method. It returns new list including duplicates.

```
var results = list1.Concat(article);
```

Also you can use [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb909044(v=vs.90).aspx) if you need new list excluding duplicates.

```
var results = list1.Union(article);
```

Also, `List` has [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method.

```
list1.AddRange(article);
```